# android make a textview like ms office text box

Tags: android, textbox, textview

I have a new problem.

The project need a textview with a bitmap(I have make it into 9 patch) as background,but users can resize its width and height with gesture,just like a text box in ms office that users can use mouse to reize the text box and the text in it will be re-published.

Here is my code:
1.this is to mark down to save the attribute of the textview. publicET is a textview.

```
                ts.setPositionX(publicET.getLeft());
                ts.setPositionY(publicET.getTop());
                ts.setLength(publicET.getBottom());
                ts.setWidth(publicET.getRight());
```

2.then I show this textview, I set this attribute of the textview:

```
                TextObject tObj = new TextObject();
                tObj.setId(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(id)));
                tObj.setPageId(getPageNum);
                tObj.setAlbumId(albumId);
                tObj.setContent(publicET.getText().toString());
                tObj.setPositionX(textPositionX);
                tObj.setPositionY(textPositionY);
                tObj.setLength(textPositionB);
                tObj.setWidth(textPositionR);
                tObj.setColor(curPicBackColor);
                tObj.setSize(curTextFontSize);
                tObj.setTextFont(typefacestr);
                publicET.setTag(tObj);
                publicET.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
```

TestObject class is like this:

```
public class TextObject {

private Integer id;
private Integer pageId;
private Integer albumId;
private String content;
private Integer positionX;
private Integer positionY;
private Integer length;
private Integer width;
private String color;
private Integer size;
private String textFont;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public Integer getPageId() {
    return pageId;
}
public void setPageId(Integer pageId) {
    this.pageId = pageId;
}
public Integer getAlbumId() {
    return albumId;
}
public void setAlbumId(Integer albumId) {
    this.albumId = albumId;
}
public String getContent() {
    return content;
}
public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}
public Integer getPositionX() {
    return positionX;
}
public void setPositionX(Integer positionX) {
    this.positionX = positionX;
}
public Integer getPositionY() {
    return positionY;
}
public void setPositionY(Integer positionY) {
    this.positionY = positionY;
}
public Integer getLength() {
    return length;
}
public void setLength(Integer length) {
    this.length = length;
}
public Integer getWidth() {
    return width;
}
public void setWidth(Integer width) {
    this.width = width;
}
public String getColor() {
    return color;
}
public void setColor(String color) {
    this.color = color;
}
public Integer getSize() {
    return size;
}
public void setSize(Integer size) {
    this.size = size;
}
public String getTextFont() {
    return textFont;
}
public void setTextFont(String textFont) {
    this.textFont = textFont;
}
```

}

I can't control the attribute of this textView to show in the right place. I checked the position by log is right.
looking forward for you to help me. thank you.

Comment: I found the solution now.

I have set the width of the textview follow setting the layout params and it works,just like textview.setWidth(intpx)

Comment: Please, add the solution as an answer and accept, so the question will be closed.

Comment: I have already posed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is my code and it works:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramst = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        paramst.setMargins(o.getPositionX(), o.getPositionY(),
                o.getWidth(), o.getLength());
        TextView e = new TextView(this);        
        e.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edittext_bg2);
        e.setLayoutParams(paramst);
        e.setWidth(o.getWidth()-o.getPositionX());
```